# Invalid column name in SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have the following code to delete information from a table if a booking is cancelled but I am receiving the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgDelBooking, Line 10
>   Invalid column name 'BookingStatus'.

However the column name is definitely correct.

Here is my code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER trgDelBooking
ON HVCBookings
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Inserted

    DELETE FROM HVCActivityBooking
    WHERE PartyID = (SELECT PartyID FROM inserted)
      AND BookingStatus = 'CANCELLED'
END
GO
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe the database:  `HVCActivityBooking.BookingStatus` does  not exist.

Comment: please provide the table structure also.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your statement updates 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `(SELECT PartyID FROM inserted)` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: @marc_s: I agree with your assessment, but if `Inserted` has more than one row, won't it give the `Subquery returned more than 1 value` error? I wouldn't expect that to work differently in a trigger (as opposed to a query outside of a trigger).

Comment: @BenThul: yes, probably - you're right on this one. The whole trigger is flawed as it is.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the issue with the column name, your trigger is assuming that `inserted` has only one row.  That is a really bad assumption.  The query should be:

```
DELETE FROM HVCActivityBooking
WHERE PartyID IN (SELECT PartyID FROM inserted) AND
      BookingStatus = 'CANCELLED';
```

Of course, this doesn't fix the unknown column problem.  It just makes the trigger much safer.

EDIT:  If `BookingStatus` is in `HVCBookings`, then the `WHERE` condition can go in the subquery:

```
DELETE FROM HVCActivityBooking
WHERE PartyID IN (SELECT i.PartyID FROM inserted i WHERE i.BookingStatus = 'CANCELLED');
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I moved the condition from the DELETE query to the SELECT as BookingStatus was in HVCBookings not HVCActivityBookings as you mentioned, rookie mistake. Thanks again